# How to browse/search Clojure Docs within Eclipse+CounterClockWise?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

Three questions here related to Eclipse and Clojure:

1. {:subject read-clojure-docs} 
   Is there a way to browse Clojure docs within Eclipse+CounterClockWise?
2. {:subject read-java-docs}
   It might be useful if I can search Java Docs in Eclipse as well, is that possible?
3. {:subject configure-repl-window} 
   When I watch Chas Emerick's video, I saw there's a line separator in the REPL window in Eclipse: it helps to separate my input and the evaluation, however, the eval and input in my Eclipse looks like in one window. How to set up this line in Eclipse?

Thanks.

Edit(2014-05-26):
Question 3 Solved by install a EclipseColorScheme.

Comment: Maybe it's not wise to ask three questions in one post. Should I ask them separately?